# Cast to custom object at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, razor-pages

Today I have several models/classes like these:

```
public class Event
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Reportage
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

These are each a part of several Razor pages, that has code that is more or less 100% same but a few lines, which are not, e.g. like this one, being unique on every page:

```
List<Event> itemList = Utility.GetCachedData<List<Event>>("event.json");
```

To get a more maintainable code, I decided to try to use as much generic code as possible, and the first issue I had were how to check if a given property existed, and if, assign that one of my defaults.

For that I found how-to using `reflection`, and did:

```
var pi = itemList[0].GetType().GetProperty("Date");
if (pi != null)
    pi.SetValue(itemList[0], DateTime.Now, null);
```

Next step were to do something similar e.g with `List<Event> itemList;`, and for that I found `Convert.ChangeType(object, type)`, and did:

```
var itemList =  Convert.ChangeType(itemObj, typeof(List<Event>));
```

The problem with this one is, that I can't do this to get/set the `Date`

```
itemList[0].Date
```

Is there a way to solve that at runtime (other than with `reflection`), and use standard *dot notation* to get/set values?

Comment: Why wouldn't you instead of using reflection, just write `itemList[0].Date = DateTime.Now`?

Comment: What do you want `itemList.Date` to do? You're trying to assing a property to an object that doesn't have it. Your `Convert` is creating a `List<Event>` not an `Event` after all. The example is confusing me :/

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Sorry, mistyped that line...updated question.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but can't you just set a default value for the `Date` property of your `Event` class? `public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @MikeBrind -- Thanks Mike, and I do with some, but some is (in my CMS solution) customer based values, and read from a config file, so it is a little more complicated than what it appears here. Asking as I'm an old VB coder and just wanted to make sure there weren't any C# tricks :)

Comment: I wouldn't call using reflection more maintainable. In general, this seems to be an XY problem. Ask about the issue you're actually trying to solve, not the solution you came up with that you *think* will solve it. What is different between the models passed to these views that you can't generalize the Razor code?

Comment: @ChrisPratt -- Thanks Chris, I might have used a less accurate wording here, and I guess it can partially be an XY-problem, though what I really wanted to ask would end up being too broad :) so I am trying to break things down until I have enough technical facts (been VB-coder for 20 years and need to wrap my head around C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve that at runtime (other than with reflection), and use standard dot notation to get/set values?

You can't use the dot notation to set a property `Date` of a type `Event` unless you actually cast the variable to a `Event` first:

```
var item =  (Event)Convert.ChangeType(itemObj, typeof(Event));
item.Date = ...;
```

Obviously this assumes that `ChangeType` actually returns an `Event`.

Please refer to the following blog post for more information.

[Generic type parameters and dynamic types in C#](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/10/31/generic-type-parameters-and-dynamic-types-in-csharp/)

Comment: I suspected this...thanks for confirming it, and thanks for the link, useful to me.